# Nginx "add before body" / "add after body" but only on content types

Tags: nginx

Okay, I have a nginx config and location. I would like to add some html above and below the body, but only on html pages, so I would like to do *something* like this:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://internal.upstreamserver

    if $response_header == "text/html" {

        add_before_body /statics/before.html;
        add_after_body /statics/after.html;
    }
}
```

My understanding is that I can't use an if because it executes at the wrong point of the cycle, and some modules do tie into the rewrite step, so whats the module to look into / use ? (I am using the nginx-python mod for other access-control elements, but this doesn't have a hook into the rewrite stage, and I don't have the C abilities or nginx knowledge to patch that feature in :S)

Comment: Have you tried sub_filter: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html#sub_filter